# Why is this jQuery UI sortreceive event not firing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a single draggable bound to multiple sortables. The sortables are all table rows (of class "spec_row") and are connected to the draggable correctly.

I am using delegated binding to manage the sortable events. Here are some example bindings:

```
$("div#tabs").on("sortstart", "tr.spec_row", function(event, ui) { alert("start"); });
$("div#tabs").on("sortchange", "tr.spec_row", function(event, ui) { alert("change"); });
$("div#tabs").on("sortstop", "tr.spec_row", function(event, ui) { alert("stop"); });
```

In all of the above events, the corresponding alert message pops up as expected. However for some reason, the "sortreceive" event doesn't execute:

```
$("div#tabs").on("sortreceive", "tr.spec_row", function(event, ui) { alert("receive"); });
```

What really confuses me is that I was previously using IDs (instead of classes) to uniquely identify the spec rows (but had to change to classes for reasons beyond the scope of this question). When I was using IDs, the "sortreceive" event was executing just fine.

For what it's worth, I'm using jQuery UI 1.8.16 (and there are no bug reports that I can see).

I will send a postcard all the way from South Africa (the postcard will have lions and elephants and everything) to whoever manages to solve this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/zXGL8/2/

Comment: Thanks for this Aamir. I have re-created the scenario on jsFiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/zXGL8/21/) and for some reason it works!? Yet it doesn't work on our development server. I'll come back to this post if I don't manage to figure out why.

FYI: the sortable rows in div#dynamic_container get updated continuously which might have something to do with it. But as far as I can tell we are re-initialising the sortables and draggable every time correctly.

Comment: Ok it turns out that upgrading to jQuery UI 1.8.23 did the trick. I have no idea why. I cannot see anything in the bug tracker or the change list about this issue.

Comment: so you are going to send me the postcard? :D